# Q: PayPal REST API PHP: How to get details of payment?

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

Okay, I managed to create a Webhook and I'm now trying to receive `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` and `PAYMENT.SALE.REFUNDED` events. So far I got:

```
$webhookEvent = new \PayPal\Api\WebhookEvent();
$webhookEvent->fromJson($requestBody);
$payment = $webhookEvent->getResource();
```

But how can I get payment-details now like amount, transaction-id or payerinfo? It seems like `$payment->getAmount()` doesn't work. It seems that payment is just an array of object(PayPal\Common\PayPalModel) so how do I get objects like API/Payment from it?